# Analytic function $f$ on $|z|<2$ such that $f(e^{i\theta})=e^{-i\theta}?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an analytic function $f$ on $|z|<2$ such that $f(e^{i\theta})=e^{-i\theta},\theta\in[0,2\pi]?$

According to me by Identity theorem $f(z)=\frac{1}{z},$ which is not analytic. Am i right? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that's right. Even without the identity theorem you can already see that $$\oint_{|z|=1} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta} ie^{i \theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta = 2\pi i \ne 0.$$

Comment: Thanks...............

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function, because, if $\gamma\colon[0,2\pi]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is defined by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$, then $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$ (by Cauchy's theorem). But$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt=2\pi i\neq0.$$